# Sparql : How to get value from either property but stop if the value of a property found

Tags: sparql, triplestore

I am trying to get the ?wdProperty1 that has label in either rdfs:label OR skos:altLabel, but I want the query to stop searching the skos:altLabel if the value "length" is already found in rdfs:label . This is for efficiency purpose, the query below is simplified from actual query. I tried to use the "?" but it still return the ?wdProperty1 from both property.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  *
WHERE 
    { 
      ?wdProperty1  ( rdfs:label | (skos:altLabel)? ) "length"@en;
    } 

LIMIT 10
```

EDIT : This is what I am trying to achieve in algo explanation

```
if ( ?wdProperty1 rdfs:label "length" )
{
    print "length exist in rdfs:label"
}
else if( ?wdProperty1 skos:label "length" )
{
   print "length exist in skos:label"
}
```

Reason I want to do this is for efficiency, because same label can exist in both rdfs:label and skos:altLabel, but I only need to know one if it, but this query will return multiple ?ent and ?wdtPorperty so statement of "?ent ?wdtProperty1 ?val." does not have to go through too many permutations. Such as the query below to find the inventor of light bulb.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?ent ?wdtProperty ?val ?valLabel 
WHERE { 
  
    VALUES ?label1 { rdfs:label skos:altLabel } ?ent ?label1 "light bulb"@en.    
  
    VALUES ?labelB1 { rdfs:label skos:altLabel } ?wdProperty1 ?labelB1 "inventor"@en; 
    
    wikibase:directClaim ?wdtProperty1. 
    ?ent ?wdtProperty1 ?val. 
    OPTIONAL { ?val rdfs:label ?valLabel FILTER(lang(?valLabel) = "en") } 

} 

LIMIT 10
```

Comment: your sample query can only return a single result unless the bindings of `?wdProperty1` would be blank nodes.

Comment: @UninformedUser Hi, I don't understand, from my testing, it return multiple result which is combination of both property, you can try to delete one of the property each time. https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%20%2a%0AWHERE%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FwdProperty1%20%20%28%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%20%7C%20skos%3AaltLabel%20%20%29%20%22length%22%40en%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0A%0ALIMIT%2010

Comment: I meant, it doesn't return duplicates. Indeed, it returns as many results as there are with the English label `"length"`

Comment: So, to rephrase your question, you want only results with `skos:label` if there are no results for `rdfs:label`? May I ask why? But to answer your question. I doubt it's possible to avoid evaluation of triple patterns by SPARQL language itself. Indeed, a query optimizer might get lucky if some `limit` has been set, to just evaluate a subquery maybe - but that's all I can think of. To prefer values specific one could use `coalesce` but that's not enough for your question.

Comment: @UninformedUser Hi, yes, I want to get the result of rdfs:label first if it exist, then don't look anymore at skos:label. It's for efficiency purpose so that the following triple statement don't have to look through too many possibilities, please see my EDIT for more details explanation. Thank you for always so helpful to me btw.